# How to pass a value form db to popup windows

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass value to popup windows by using a tag with href when I click a 
get values form db into hidden layer how to passing values by js.

A tag code

```
<a 'href=index.php?id=3'></a>
```

Hidden layer

```
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='content'>
<h2>Well Hello!</h2>
<p>
<? if ( isset($_GET['id'])){         
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id ;} ?>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

js code

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
 $('.wrap, a').toggleClass('active');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: [checkout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) the correct syntax for `<a>` tag!

Comment: please add the names of the scripts to your code. It's not clear which code is in one file

Comment: also `<?` should be `<?php`. It might work in your corrent configuration, but likely will break on others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this the javascript way, see this example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a.toggle-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behaviour of the link that would reload the page
    $('.wrap, a.toggle-wrap').removeClass('active'); // remove class active on every link clicking
    var target_id = $(this).attr("data-id"); //get the desired id from link
    var wrap_element = $('.wrap[data-target=' + target_id + '] p');
    var link_element = $('a[data-id=' + target_id + ']');
    link_element.toggleClass('active');
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "someOtherScriptThatOnlyOutputsResults.php",
      data: "id="+target_id,
      success: function(resultData) {
        wrap_element.html(resultData).toggleClass('active'); // only toggle desired ids
      }, error:  function() {
        wrap_element.html('Could not load data').toggleClass('active');
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: none;
}

.wrap.active {
  display: block;
}

a {
  color: green;
}

a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="toggle-wrap" data-id="3">Link 3</a>
<a class="toggle-wrap" data-id="4">Link 4</a>

<div class="wrap" data-target="3">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Well Hello content 3!</h2>
    <p>Your db content related to id 3 from database, using php.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap" data-target="4">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Well Hello content 4!</h2>
    <p>Your db content related to id 4 from database, using php.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add identifiers to the hidden wrap(s) and the link(s) and work with those. By using queries as seen in the js snippet, you can target certain HTML tags. Use CSS display to hide and show your wrap tag.

Create a new PHP file **someOtherScriptThatOnlyOutputsResults.php** to get and return data:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=someHost;dbname=someDatabase', 'someUser', 'somePass');
  $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT columnWithContent FROM yourContentTable WHERE id = ?");
  $statement->execute(array($_GET['id']));
  $row = $statement->fetch();
  $content = $row['columnWithContent'];
  echo $content;

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks bro but I want to get values form db by id

Comment: Do you mean on the fly? As in you click the link and then load some db data into the wrap?

Comment: yas that what i need

Comment: i added an ajax call to the javascript bit to request another php script for the data, passing the id with which you can query your database for content to display in your wrap containers.

Comment: This is usually not the place to just ask for code.. you should have figured that out yourself. However i added the php bit for the sake of completeness and because i can :)